# Download de arquivo CSV no diretório WEB

Tags: php, csv

Estou tentando fazer o download de um arquivo CSV no diretório mas o mesmo é descarregado em .TXT

Tentativas sem sucesso (PHP 7.1)

```
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8')
header("Content-Type: application/csv");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
```

Código

```
<a download href="<?php echo$csv; ?>" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> BAIXAR CSV</a>

$csv ='assets/tabelas-csv/planilha-produtos-'.$date.'.csv';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faz mais simples. Se vc ja tem o arquivo e sabe onde ele ta so adiciona a tag download no link.

ex:

```
<a href="pasta/diretorio/nomedoarquivo.csv" download="nomedoarquivo.csv" target="_blank">Click here to download</a>
```

resolve ?

Comment: Tentei de tudo menos isso e funcionou, obrigado !